# Display messages with thymeleaf in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm tryting to add externalized messages from a properties file in a thymeleaf html template. I have a file `messages_es.properties` located in `i18n/messages` with this inside:

```
estimado=Estimado:
```

In my html template i have the following

```html
<div th:text="#{estimado}">Estimado placeholder</div>
```

but then, the html I get is the following:

```html
<div>??estimado_es??</div>
```

Is anyone able to help me?

---

This is the configuration i have added in order to make this work:

```java
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("custom")
    public ITemplateResolver thymeleafTemplateResolver(){
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine thymeleafTemplateEngine(@Qualifier("custom") ITemplateResolver templateResolver) {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
        templateEngine.setTemplateEngineMessageSource(messageSource());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    @Description("Spring Message Resolver")
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("i18n/messages");
        return messageSource;
    }
```

In my application.yml file:

```yaml
spring.messages.basename: i18n/messages
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should add `classpath:` as prefix to your base name.
secondly if you have baseName set to`i18n/messages` app will look for `i18n/messages_es.properties`

if i understand correctly your file path is `i18n/messages/messages_es.properties`
so you need to set baseName to: `classpath:i18n/messages/messages`